# Text editor toolbar z-index conflict with location plugin pop

Tags: css, wp-admin

I am working on project where location plugin is already is installed.When i try to test it after update the wordpress to new version.The editor toolbar on edit page z index is higher then the location pop.How i can fix this issue.Pic attached to explain the problem.[image]

You can when i click on location the popup appears but the editor toolbar is still showing.

Comment: Change the z-index in the toolbar or in the mask the location popup is using to grey out the page behind it? I don't think the location popup is standard: it's probably come from a plugin or theme.

Comment: yeah its come from plugin but when i try to edit wordpress editor toolbar css.It still loading the old z-index.I don't know how to fix this issue.